# Build and run container but there is no container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile look like this

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER abc <abc.yur@gmail.com>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install golang-go git
RUN mkdir /work
ENV GOPATH=/work

RUN go get github.com/abc/golang
RUN go build github.com/abc/golang

CMD /golang -addr $ADDR  -workers $WORKERS
```

So I want to build and run container but after the building (`docker build .`) I can not run this container. So when I am running `docker ps -a` or `docker ps`  there is not container to run

Answer (score 2):

```
docker build .
```

This creates the image and not a container. You need to use

```
docker images
```

To get the list of images.

`docker ps` will show when you run a container using something like below

```
docker run -d <image>
```

Comment: Thanks . But I can not set the port and other variables , for example
docker run -d <image> -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 -e ADDR=0.0.0.0:8080
I got the following error 
**Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"-p\": executable file not found in $PATH".**

Comment: Your argument order is wrong. It should be `docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 -e ADDR=0.0.0.0:8080 <image>`